# Reposition dropdown of HTML <SELECT> element

Tags: html, css

I there a way to move the list dropdown of html select element a couple of pixels down.

Comment: In a word, with just a `<select>`, "no". Why do you even want to do this?

Comment: Are you able to place a DIV around the select? If so you could simply set padding-top:2px to that DIV. Alternatively you could absolutely position it if possible within your page set-up.

Comment: I have a combobox whose dropdown list popups a couple of pixals above the combobox because of unknown reason.

Comment: It seems the page is messed up at some point hence the problem. The page was 64k line long hence finding the problem will be tedious. I solved this by creating a custom dropdown using jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

theoretically you could hack it setting border-bottom of the select element, e.g.:

```
select { border-bottom: 5px solid transparent; }
```

but there are better ways, like custom plugins for dropdowns, etc.

Comment: can you give me the name of any plugin that would render the dropdown exactly as HTML select. Your method do what it says but did not solved my problem.